# Why is my Rust program that performs array reversal slower than the equivalent Go program?

Tags: go, rust

I am initialising an array and then reversing it a number of times to see the performance.

I want to understand if I have written code which cannot be compared or is Rust really so bad that it is taking so much time?

Here is the build and timing process of Rust:

```
rustc main.rs
time ./main
```

This runs and goes on and on. Which is surprising

#### Rust

```
fn reverse(mylist: &mut Vec<u16>) {
    let length = mylist.len();

    let mid_length = length / 2;

    for number in 0..mid_length {
        let mut a = mylist[number];
        let mut b = mylist[length - number - 1];

        mylist[number] = b;

        mylist[length - number - 1] = a;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let array_size = 100000;

    let iterations = 100000;

    let mut v = vec![0u16; array_size];

    for _ in 0..iterations {
        reverse(&mut v);
    }
}
```

#### Go

The Go code does exactly what Rust code is doing above. The important thing to note is that Go has Garbage Collection where as Rust does not. Surprisingly, Go does the job in less than 6 seconds:

```
go build main.go
time ./main 100000 100000

real    0m5.932s
user    0m5.928s
sys 0m0.004s
```

#### Go

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func reverse(mylist []int) []int {

    length := len(mylist)
    half := int(length / 2)

    for i := 0; i < half; i++ {

        mylist[i], mylist[length-i-1] = mylist[length-i-1], mylist[i]

    }   

    return mylist

}

func main() {

    array_size, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    iterations, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])

    mylist := make([]int, array_size)

    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        reverse(mylist)

    }

}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? [`Vec::reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reverse).

Comment: The first issue I can think of is that by default `rustc` compiles in Debug mode as far as I know. Repeat the experiment with the `-O` flag (for optimizations).

Comment: @ljedrz: Basic algorithm is similar (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/src/core/slice.rs.html#432), it simply uses `unsafe` to avoid bounds checking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. in any case you were right - it runs pretty fast with optimizations on.

Comment: @ljedrz: How fast? If the optimizer was clever enough, this should be a no-op. Go taking 6s for a no-op is slow as hell.

Comment: @ljedrz wanted to test on fundamental approach rather than using built-in functions

Comment: @Tahseen: This is not a built-in, I linked to the code so you can see its implementation. The only difference with your approach is the use of `unsafe` and `get_unchecked_mut` to avoid bounds-checking should the optimizer not be smart enough to realize it's unnecessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You were right about -O flag. If you reply, I will mark it as an Answer :-) Also I wanted to say, some how Java is able to manage sub 6 seconds for same thing

Comment: @MatthieuM. fast, but not noop-fast, perhaps due to bounds checking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I mean Java is fastest even when it has GC. Faster than Go and Rust

Comment: @Tahseen: I think `rustc` could be improved to teach `LLVM` which alloc/dealloc functions it uses, and then LLVM would be able to optimize this to `fn main() {}` which would be faster than Java. It should also somehow indicate to LLVM that the content is all 0, as this would allow optimizing out the `reverse` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `rustc` (and `cargo`) compile in Debug mode. It was judged the most useful default as one compiles most often during development.

Debug mode, especially in your code, includes a *lot* of checks: each access to `mylist[..]` is guarded by a bounds check, among other things.

Instead, for benchmarking purposes, you want to compile with optimizations. If using `rustc` directly, this is as simple as passing the `-O` flag.

---

As noted by @ljerdz, there is a [`[T]::reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reverse) method, it is even more efficient than your implementation as it internally uses `unsafe` to elide bounds-checking.

A quick check on the playground, however, does not reveal any outlandish difference between your `reverse` and `Vec::reverse` in your case; the optimizer was already smart enough to elide the bounds checks.

Unfortunately it is not smart enough to elide the loop, likely because it does not realize that `__rust_alloc_zeroed` and `__rust_dealloc` are memory allocation/deallocation routines and have no observable side-effect.

Comment: I tested Vec::reverse as mentioned by @ljerdz and am getting 2x improvement in performance. But again as I said, intent was to test performance using fundamentals. And your -O suggestion was the right one

Comment: @Tahseen Vec is not a fundamentals brick of rust. It have overhead when use it as you do.